# How to get a path for script-fu function: gimp-drawable-edit-stroke-item

Tags: gimp, script-fu

I am struggling with getting the actual path (or vector) object from an id. I want to stroke a path and the currently advised way of doing so seems to be the method `gimp-drawable-edit-stroke-item`. This needs an item as input. By the way I tried to find a list of all predefined types in script-fu but also didn't find anything. So I am not sure what the typ Item really is but it looks like you can pass a vector to it.

All I can find so far to identify a path is using `(cadr(gimp-image-get-vectors p-image))` which seems to only give me an id. As the following `(gimp-drawable-edit-stroke-item p-drawable (cadr(gimp-image-get-vectors p-image)))` leads to an "Error: Invalid type for argument 2 to gimp-drawable-edit-stroke-item".

Answer (score 0):

Having to navigate lists instead of using names for fields is the reason why I never bothered with Scheme/script-fu since Gimp can be scripted in Python.

This said, with my limited Lisp knowledge:

- `(gimp-image-get-vectors p-image)` returns a `(count (v1 v2 v3 ...))` list
- so `(cadr (gimp-image-get-vectors p-image))` returns the list, and not a single item of the list.

You can get the "active path" directly with `(gimp-image-get-vectors p-image)` (using the paths list doesn't tell you which path in the list is meant by the user anyway).

Answer (score 0):

"I want to stroke a path"

Rather than gimp-drawable-edit-stroke-item, gimp-pencil (or gimp-brush) can do it:

```
(define (stroke-path drawable color width . path)
  (gimp-context-set-line-miter-limit 5)         ; default: 10, default mitre up to 60 pixels
  (gimp-context-set-stroke-method STROKE-LINE)  ; default STROKE-PAINT-METHOD
  (gimp-context-set-line-cap-style CAP-BUTT)    ; CAP-ROUND, CAP-SQUARE
  (gimp-context-set-line-join-style JOIN-ROUND) ; JOIN-MITER, JOIN-ROUND, JOIN-BEVEL
  (gimp-context-set-foreground color)
  (gimp-context-set-line-width width)           ; default: 6

  (let ((vec (apply vector path)))
    (gimp-pencil drawable (vector-length vec) vec)
   )
  )
```